# Automated rollback in Informix 14 database?

Tags: database, informix, rollback

I have some scripts including DDL and DML transactions that use an Informix 14 database that I want to run some tests against.

If the tests fail they will often leave the database in an inconsistent state that needs to be manually resolved before the tests can be run again.

I would like to automate this so that the tests do not require manual intervention before running the tests again.
So, is it possible to use rollback and savepoint without locking the database and run some tests on the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute `BEGIN WORK` (or just `BEGIN`), then everything you do afterwards will be part of the same transaction until you explicitly execute `COMMIT WORK` (or just `COMMIT`) or `ROLLBACK WORK` (or just `ROLLBACK`) — or until your program exits without explicitly ending the transaction.  If your program terminates unexpectedly or carelessly (without explicitly completing the transaction), the transaction will be rolled back.

The transaction will manage all the DDL and DML operations — with the sole exception of some caveats with the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement.  There are some restrictions on what you can do with the truncated table — basically, it cannot be modified again until the transaction completes.

Of course, this assumes your database is logged.  You can't have transactional control in an unlogged database.

Comment: so before commiting the transaction, the database would be locked and i can not run my tests with application to decide rollback the work or not. how can i do rollback automatically without getting database in lock mode ?

Comment: If your tests require multiple concurrent sessions, or multiple transactions in a single session, then rollback is not the answer.  Then you have to look at PIT — Point In Time — restore from an archive created just prior to running the tests.  That's a quite different proposition, and considerably more fiddly, which is why I didn't mention it before.  Or, instead of a PIT restore, you can just do a plain restore.  That recovers the complete database up to the end of the last archive images and logical log backups.  It's still fiddly.  Do you use 'ON-Tape' or 'ON-Bar' for backups?

Comment: ontape and onbar for large databases is not my prefer actually. because of the long time to restoring and keeping the database down for long time is not ok. i just want to rollback for example 100 DDL and DML transaction , not the whole database with millions of records for each table.